# Xcode 7 Memory Address

Tags: ios, memory-management

In Xcode 6:

```
int i = 17; 
printf ("i stores its value at %p\n", &i);
```

I will see something like this:

```
i stores its value at 0xbffff738
```

But in Xcode 7, its output format is:

```
i stores its value at 0x7fff5fbff7cc
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the built architecture. The first is a 32-bit address. The second is a 64-bit address.

Comment: int is 32bit, why does Xcode 7 place int into a 64-bit address instead of 32- bit address?

Comment: Because memory addressing is based on the architecture of the system your software is running on. in a 64-bit architecture, memory addresses will always be 64 bits regardless of what's there in that memory location. What you are printing is the address of that int not the int itself. So whether it's any of the primitive data types like `int` or `char`, or an object that can be of any size, its address will be 64 bits. Think of memory as a street, and memory addresses as the house numbers. House numbers have nothing to do with the number of people living there!